# I have problems with JSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

There is a problem with JSON.

**HistoryFragment.java**

```
private View rootView;
ListView list;
AppSharedPreference appSharedPreference;
private ProgressDialog progress;
String[] datetime;
String[] mobile;
String [] amount;
String[] operator;
String[] abpNo;
String[] optNo;
String[] rechargeStatus;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

    appSharedPreference = AppSharedPreference.getInstance(getActivity());

    callHistoryApi();

    HistoryList adapter = new HistoryList(getActivity(),datetime,mobile,amount,operator,abpNo,optNo,rechargeStatus);
    list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void callHistoryApi() {

    Map<String, String> param = null;
    try {
        param = new HashMap<String, String>();
        param.put("username", appSharedPreference.getUserName());
        param.put("trpass", appSharedPreference.getPassword());
        param.put("action", "RECH_HISTORY");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String jobjstr = param.toString();
    Log.e("LOGINREQUESTTTTTTT", jobjstr);
    if (jobjstr != null) {

        AllInOneAsyncTask asyncTask = new AllInOneAsyncTask(getActivity());
        asyncTask.setServiceResultListener(this);
        asyncTask.setServiceType(Constants.SERVICE_TYPE_GET_PROFILE);
        asyncTask.execute(param);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResult(String resultData, int requestType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestType == Constants.SERVICE_TYPE_GET_PROFILE) {
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(resultData);
            String Status = jObject.getString("Status");

            JSONArray history = jObject.getJSONArray("History");

            for (int i=0; i < history.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject oneObject = history.getJSONObject(i);
                String Datetime = oneObject.getString("Datetime");
                String Mobile = oneObject.getString("Mooble");
                String Amount = oneObject.getString("Amount");
                String Operator = oneObject.getString("Operator");
                String ABPNo = oneObject.getString("ABPNo");
                String OPTNO = oneObject.getString("OPTNO");
                String Recharge_Status = oneObject.getString("Recharge_Status");
                Log.e("HISTORYYYYYYYYYYYY",Datetime+" "+Mobile+" "+Amount+" "+Operator+" "+ABPNo+" "+
                        OPTNO+" "+Recharge_Status);
                datetime = new String[history.length()];
                mobile = new String[history.length()];
                amount = new String[history.length()];
                operator = new String[history.length()];
                abpNo = new String[history.length()];
                optNo = new String[history.length()];
                rechargeStatus = new String[history.length()];
                datetime[i] = Datetime;
                mobile[i] = Mobile;
                amount[i] = Amount;
                operator[i] = Operator;
                abpNo[i] = ABPNo;
                optNo[i] = OPTNO;
                rechargeStatus[i] = Recharge_Status;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**HistoryList.java**

```
public HistoryList(Activity context,String[] datetime,String[] mobile,String[] amount,String[] operator,String[] abpNo,
                   String[] optNo,String[] rechargeStatus) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_history, abpNo);
    this.context = context;
    this.datetime=datetime;
    this.mobile=mobile;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.operator=operator;
    this.abpNo=abpNo;
    this.optNo=optNo;
    this.rechargeStatus=rechargeStatus;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_history, null, true);

    TextView datetoday = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.id);
    TextView oper = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.operator);
    TextView amoun = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
    TextView statu = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.status);

    datetoday.setText(datetime[position]);
    txtTitle.setText("id ="+abpNo[position]);
    oper.setText(" operator ="+operator[position]);
    amoun.setText(" amount ="+amount[position]);
    statu.setText(" status ="+rechargeStatus[position]);


    return rowView;
}
```

There is a problem in this, when I open this fragment there is an error **attempt to read from null array** how can solve this problem.
please help.

Comment: on which ine it gives error?

Comment: in class HistoryList.java on line datetoday.setText(datetime[position]); @VivekMishra

Comment: Plz Check answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: create the String array objects before the for loop in onResult method as shown in the answers below, and create the HistoryList adapter object and then set the adapter after the for loop.

Comment: this is not working. 
there is an error on this line 
**super(context, R.layout.list_history, abpNo);**
 in HistoryList.java
@Darshak

Answer (score 0):

in HistryFragment.java,you have create the datatime,mobile,..etc array for every loop iteration.

```
for (int i=0; i < history.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject oneObject = history.getJSONObject(i);
                String Datetime = oneObject.getString("Datetime");
                String Mobile = oneObject.getString("Mooble");
                String Amount = oneObject.getString("Amount");
                String Operator = oneObject.getString("Operator");
                String ABPNo = oneObject.getString("ABPNo");
                String OPTNO = oneObject.getString("OPTNO");
                String Recharge_Status = oneObject.getString("Recharge_Status");
                Log.e("HISTORYYYYYYYYYYYY",Datetime+" "+Mobile+" "+Amount+" "+Operator+" "+ABPNo+" "+
                        OPTNO+" "+Recharge_Status);
                datetime = new String[history.length()];
                mobile = new String[history.length()];
                amount = new String[history.length()];
                operator = new String[history.length()];
                abpNo = new String[history.length()];
                optNo = new String[history.length()];
                rechargeStatus = new String[history.length()];
                datetime[i] = Datetime;
                mobile[i] = Mobile;
                amount[i] = Amount;
                operator[i] = Operator;
                abpNo[i] = ABPNo;
                optNo[i] = OPTNO;
                rechargeStatus[i] = Recharge_Status;
            }
```

This will the cause of the problem.create the array before the loop and add the items.

Comment: this is not working. there is an error on this line **super(context, R.layout.list_history, abpNo);** in HistoryList.java

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
    datetime = new String[history.length()];
    mobile = new String[history.length()];
    amount = new String[history.length()];
    operator = new String[history.length()];
    abpNo = new String[history.length()];
    optNo = new String[history.length()];
    rechargeStatus = new String[history.length()];

    for (int i=0; i < history.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject oneObject = history.getJSONObject(i);
        String Datetime = oneObject.getString("Datetime");
        String Mobile = oneObject.getString("Mooble");
        String Amount = oneObject.getString("Amount");
        String Operator = oneObject.getString("Operator");
        String ABPNo = oneObject.getString("ABPNo");
        String OPTNO = oneObject.getString("OPTNO");
        String Recharge_Status = oneObject.getString("Recharge_Status");
            Log.e("HISTORYYYYYYYYYYYY",Datetime+" "+Mobile+" "+Amount+" "+Operator+" "+ABPNo+" "+
                    OPTNO+" "+Recharge_Status);

            datetime[i] = Datetime;
            mobile[i] = Mobile;
            amount[i] = Amount;
            operator[i] = Operator;
            abpNo[i] = ABPNo;
            optNo[i] = OPTNO;
            rechargeStatus[i] = Recharge_Status;
        }
```

You are creating new array in for-loop - this is wrong thing.

Comment: this is not working.
there is an error on this line 
**super(context, R.layout.list_history, abpNo);**
in HistoryList.java

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is the string array not getting the values.Do the following.
Initialize your String array just before the loop begins,

```
    datetime = new String[history.length()];
    mobile = new String[history.length()];
    amount = new String[history.length()];
    operator = new String[history.length()];
    abpNo = new String[history.length()];
    optNo = new String[history.length()];
    rechargeStatus = new String[history.length()];
```

And only after that begin your loop iteration.
Else it will reset the array on each iteration of the loop.

```
for (int i=0; i < history.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject oneObject = history.getJSONObject(i);
                String Datetime = oneObject.getString("Datetime");
                String Mobile = oneObject.getString("Mooble");
                String Amount = oneObject.getString("Amount");
                String Operator = oneObject.getString("Operator");
                String ABPNo = oneObject.getString("ABPNo");
                String OPTNO = oneObject.getString("OPTNO");
                String Recharge_Status = oneObject.getString("Recharge_Status");
                Log.e("HISTORYYYYYYYYYYYY",Datetime+" "+Mobile+" "+Amount+" "+Operator+" "+ABPNo+" "+
                        OPTNO+" "+Recharge_Status);

                datetime[i] = Datetime;
                mobile[i] = Mobile;
                amount[i] = Amount;
                operator[i] = Operator;
                abpNo[i] = ABPNo;
                optNo[i] = OPTNO;
                rechargeStatus[i] = Recharge_Status;
            }
```

Happy coding...

Comment: this is not working. there is an error on this line **super(context, R.layout.list_history, abpNo);** in HistoryList.java

Comment: make sure that your string array size is greater than zero before populate the list

Comment: change super(context, R.layout.list_history, abpNo); line to super(context, R.layout.list_history, datetime, mobile, amount,operator, abpNo,
                    optNo,rechargeStatus); and check

Comment: we can't do this.
there is an error can't resolve method.

Comment: then try to comment out that constructor and try again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First print a log for the `datetime` get value or not.

and give the condition before set value in `TextView` check like this.

```
if(datetime[position]!=null){ 

    datetoday.setText(datetime[position]);

}
```

it's possible `datatime[position]` return `null`.

Comment: yes it is returning null value,but why?
you have any solution for this?